# How to vertically align radio buttons with text on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I wrote the HTML below to display two radio buttons and some text.

```
<input id="radio1"  type="radio"   checked="checked"/>Create the application name <br/>
<input id="radio2"  type="radio"/> Create the  Source name
```

My issue is that the radio buttons and the text are not aligning properly.  The radio buttons are displaying a little bit below the text. How do I align the radio buttons and the text on the same line with proper alignment?

Comment: use display: inline-block and vertical-align: middle

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/xS8zj/4/)**</kbd>

#### vertical-align: middle:

Aligns the vertical midpoint of the box with the baseline of the parent box plus half the x-height of the parent.

The problem seems to be caused by the fact browsers commonly add some random uneven margins to radio buttons and checkboxes.

Use inline style, weird but true:

```
<input type="radio" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px;"> Label
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px;"> Label
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px;"> Label
```

Edit

[this short explanation](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) by Gavin Kistner, which is useful. I tried out the final suggestion on that page, which seems to render respectably in Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera, and Safari.

What I did was add `td{ line-height:1.5em }`

Comment: tried same style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px;" but not aligning properly.inline style only i applied to input .

Comment: then there must be some other issue, it makes it clear. Have you added any css styles for input or radio or label ?

Comment: same fiddle tried in my page not aligning proerly.i think table tr styles are effecting the inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear what you're after specifically..but:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xS8zj/1/)

Add:

```
input{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

You may also want to chage this to `vertical-align:middle;margin:0;` depending on your requirements.

Comment: i need to set the radio button and text in proper alignment in same line .my issue radio button and text not aligning properly in same line.

Comment: i tried inline style vertical-align:middle;margin:0; but not solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try it below code...

```
 input {float: left;
margin-top: 3px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

add style for input type as

```
input
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and avoid the space in front of **Create the  Source name**.

```
<input id="radio2"  type="radio"/> Create the  Source name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input id="radio1"  type="radio"   checked="checked"/><label for="radio1">Create the application name</label> 
 <input id="radio2"  type="radio" /><label for="radio2">Create the application name</label> 

input,label{
       vertical-align: top;
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B6G5H/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form >
          <label>
            <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" />
            Man</label>
     <label><br>
            <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" />
            Women</label>
        </form>



/******this will help you********/
```