# Align test options with respective `radio` buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've created a simple quiz application.
How can I vertically align text with `radio` buttons.?
Here is the code- [Codepen](http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad/pen/VaKMBJ).
The problem specially arises with long text `label`s.
For example, in question no.9,12 & 14, the misalignment is pretty evident.
I tried a lot of solutions available on stackoverflow, but none of them seem to be working for me.(eg:[How to vertically align radio buttons with text on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218692/how-to-set-the-css-for-align-the-radio-button-and-the-text-in-same-line))

Comment: Because your label is taking the whole width. If you set the following CSS rule to your label: `label{display:inline-block; width: 80%;}` the lay-out will be fixed or use the option as @Goombah gave below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
label
{
  display: inline;
}
```

Like [here (Codepen)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWpPYR)!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the **label** style from inline-block to **inline**, this way it won't break when the solution takes more than one line:

[Edited CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMprob)

```
label{
  display: inline;
}
```

Hope it helps!